# Installing Sencha Touch 2 framework

Tags: extjs, touch

I've a problem with getting Sencha Touch to work. I'm using a MacBook Pro and it's really been a hell installing this framework. Sencha don't seem to have any documentation that fits the latest version of their product and there is no way for me to download an older version from their website. Therefore I need your help!

I've downloaded Sencha SDK, SDKTools and their Cmd-software. The version of the SDK is 2.1.1, the SDKTools is 2.0.0 and I dont know the version of the cmd-software. All three softwares is however the latest from Senchas webpage.

I've placed the SDK under the root of the web server, and I've also installed the SDKTools in the root.

This is the structure I'm currently using:
Root of webbserver:
- SDK
- SDKTools

The SDK works in the way that I can surf into it, by using my browser into the "SDK"-folder. On that page I can view examples of Sencha applications.

When I go the SDK folder via the Terminal, and type "Sencha" - I get the error:
**[WARN] The current working directory (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SDK) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.**

I've googled this and tried the following actions:
1. Placed the SDKTools in the same folder as the SDK.
2. Created a systemfile named .senchasdk with the content "sdk".
3. Created a systemfile named .senchasdk with the content ".".

The first option, naturally doesn't work (didn't differ anything from the previous setup). The 2nd and 3rd action resulted in compilationerrors when typing Sencha in the SDK-folder. Example down below:
**node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SDK/command/sencha.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)**

I've also tried typing "Sencha" from the SDKTools folder, but that doesn't work either. I don't know what this problem comes from and can't find any other solutions to solve this. Does anyone know? Or have any suggestions on solution or part of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website, you can download the 2.0 version of the Sencha CMD tool which is used instead of SDKTools nowadays. However, if you use the 2.0 version you will meet nothing but trouble since that is outdated. The latest version as of right now is 3.1 and can only be downloadable from your account at support.sencha.com, and not from the download page when not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch 2.1 doesn't work with SDK Tools anymore. The documentation bundled with Sencha Touch 2.1 is not up-to-date. Here is the good documentation :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command

Comment: I'm still getting the error where the CMDtool doesn't recognize the folder as the SDK. And I dont have a clue why. Some sources say that the hidden (.senchasdk) files will help this but it doesn't. The folder I'm execute from is this one: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5461608/senchaSDK.tiff. Is this right folder?